# What means to flush something in embedded?

Tags: embedded, spi

I'm now reading some code from radio module library and I found such function:

```
void nRF24_FlushRX(void)
{
    uint8_t command = NRF24_CMD_FLUSH_RX;

    NRF24_CSN_LOW;
    nRF24_SendSpi(&command, 1);
    NRF24_CSN_HIGH;
}
```

And I wonder what does it means to flush some data via SPI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Communication modules commonly use a buffer for data received but not obtained by the application. This commands empties the buffer, and you cannot obtain the received data any more.